# Bandit problem algorithm

Tags: matlab, multiarmed-bandit

I want to write some MATLAB code for the bandit problem, but I don't know what the exact algorithm is for this problem.
Is the Epsilon-Greedy algorithm right?

I have 5 slot-machines. For example, I should play a lever 1000 times as a task, and then if the mean of one machine's rewards are maximum in comparison with the other machines' rewards, then I should play that machine's lever again for 1000 times. Then I should iterate this action 5000 times.
Is it right?

Comment: This just sounds like a greedy algorithm with a fixed window of exploration. The epsilon-greedy algorithm uses epsilon to determine the rate of exploration, which occurs with probability epsilon at each trial.

Comment: Is this what you mean?  http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Stopping/sr7.pdf